# How many turns does a Spy in Civilization 5 replaced by new recruit when killed?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Recently I installed Civilization 5 with DLC. I love playing the game with spies. But when I encounter that my spy got **'Killed in Action'**. I have search the net for this but so far I read the wiki said **'replaced after some turns'**. What is the exact number of turns? Is it based on distance of the city? strength/experience of the spy? or fixed like exactly replaced in 5 turns?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually takes about 4-6 turns. (From what I have experienced.) And I don't think it depends on the experience of the spy, all spies get replaced in the same time.